# react-router inconsistent `exact` behaviour in `matchPath()` function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have two level navigation in my application. Top level items should have different color when any of the sub-items are active. In order to achieve that, I tried using `matchPath()` function.

Top level navigation route is `/app/production`, sub item route is `/app/production/:id`.
I want `matchPath()` to return true for `/app/production` when user is on `/app/production/:id`.

This is the code I'm using for this check:

`matchPath("/app/production", { path: location.pathname, exact: false})`

Following the documentation and how `<Route>` component works, I need to set `exact` parameter to false - but I get `null` match object anyway. It's just as if `matchPath()` works with `{ exact: true }` always. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

PS. No, I can't use `<NavLink>` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by reverting the order of parameter :

```
matchPath(location.pathname, { path: "/app/production"})
```

Also, exact has a default value of false, so we can skip that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. I've messed up the order of the parameters.
Instead of:

`matchPath("/app/production", { path: location.pathname, exact: false})`

It should be:

`matchPath(location.pathname, { path: "/app/production", exact: false})`